# R: Naive Bayes makes predictions solely on apriori probabilities

Tags: r, tm, naivebayes

I am trying to train a Naive Bayes classifier in R that classifies strings of texts according to their similarity to multiple bags of words.

Here is some simplified code that replicates my problem:

```
library(tm)
library(e1071)


df <- data.frame(class = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                 text = c("sirloin steak",
                          "aaa steak",
                          "new york strip steak",
                          "sour patch kids",
                          "cherry blasters",
                          "popsicles",
                          "donuts",
                          "cakes",
                          "bread",
                          "sourdough",
                          "rye",
                          "rolled oats",
                          "loaf",
                          "bagels"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm_matrix <- as.matrix(dtm)
labels <- as.factor(df$class)

clf <- naiveBayes(dtm_matrix, labels)

predict(clf, "steak")
```

The returned output looks like this:

```
[1] 3
Levels: 1 2 3
```

When steak clearly belongs in the first class.

I can't figure out where I have gone wrong. Whenever I look at other examples of Document Term Matrices being passed into Naive Bayes it's being done the same way.

Any thoughts where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Pass a matrix with the trained features to `predict`, like `predict(clf, matrix(match(colnames(dtm_matrix), "steak", 0), nrow = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, colnames(dtm_matrix))))`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked on my example!